# Add to cart error : ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, cart, javascript

I am stuck here when i click on add to cart button the firefox console is giving the following error. `ReferenceError: productAddToCartForm is not defined` i have tried adding the `$.noConflict()` and `jQuery.noConflict()` but they are not helping.

This was working some time ago but now this throwing error although i havn't touch it for a while.

Any idea about it.

Comment: Whilst everyone here is eager to help - you have posted a lot of questions - all very much [localised](http://goo.gl/m8ASA) to you. This site is not here to answer questions about every issue you run into with your Magento store. Its a place where you can post *general* questions - where the answers will also be of benefit to other people. You should also make an effort to outline exactly [what you have tried](http://goo.gl/eGSk1). Your question above is so vague and specific to yourself - how can anyone possibly answer the question? *I have a JS error - why is it happening ... ?*

Comment: Go through a [debug process](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) first before posting - this methodology WILL identify 99% of issues with a Magento store and give you much more traceability. Then, if it still doesn't resolve your issue - outline exactly what you have done and the outcome of each *(even then, its still probably localised, but a lot easier to answer)*.  **Don't be discouraged, just make a bit more effort and post better questions**

Comment: @sonassi Thanks a lot for your kind comments. I only post a question after making reasonable effort to the problem, BTW you have very good knowledge of this platform and i learn a lot from you. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Magento - there is a block of inline JS that is outputted on each product page for the `productAddToCartForm`

For example, on a [Magento demo store](http://me-s1.sonassihosting.com)

If you view a [product](http://me-s1.sonassihosting.com/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html) and view the source of the page; search inline for `var productAddToCartForm`

You'll see a block of JS that declares the add to cart object and methods.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
    productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
....
```

View the source on your own page and you'll either see this block missing - or present, but broken because of another JS conflict/error.

The respective JS can be found in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Comment: I have checked that every thing is there. The url is http://premierpoolproducts.com/jacuzzi-j-300-series-spa-filter-cartridge-6540-476-fc-2800.html

Comment: Look at your page source. You are clearly trying to minify the HTML - and you've caused a JS error in the process. Remove your HTML minification - then remove the "TrustLogo()" call.

Comment: Thanks a lot it htmlminify extension which was behind the scene but it was working fine a time ago don't know how it stopped working..

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing something in the product details page. In the default theme there is this javascript code that adds the product to cart or to wishlist.

```
var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Make sure this code exists in your page also and the form in the product page is properly closed and named `product_addtocart_form`.
Try to make the product page as much as possible similar to the default theme product page, at least from the structural point of view (demo can be seen [here](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/blackberry-8100-pearl.html) )